# Servo going up to the limit as soon as attached

Tags: servo

I have a Futaba S148 servo (https://servodatabase.com/servo/futaba/s148)
connected to an Arduino Uno.

As soon as the script attaches the servo, it rotates to its limit and gets stuck.

I've tried several scripts, and narrowed to the simplest:

```
#include <Servo.h>  // servo library
Servo servo1;  // servo control object
void setup()
{
  //  Attach the servo1 object to digital pin 4.
  servo1.attach(10);
}
void loop()
{
}
```

Also connected the servo to the board with this:

```
#include <Servo.h>  // servo library
Servo servo1;  // servo control object
void setup()
{
  //  Attach the servo1 object to digital pin 4.
  //servo1.attach(10); <--- notice this commented out
}
void loop()
{
}
```

and then the servo remains still.

I'm using a battery pack of 4.8 V which works fine with the servo and the RC radio, so the battery and the servo, works fine together with remote control.

I have another different [SG90 servo](https://servodatabase.com/servo/towerpro/sg90) running with its own power source and connected to the pin 9, and with a different sketch, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/ServoAttach - This should answer it. The library you are using supports only 2 specific pins

Comment: oh, good thinking..but it is now in pin 11, because I tried so many things that didn't work out...I've tried with 9 and 10 also with the same result. I'll try again just in case and update the question if nothing changes.

Comment: tested, same result, once attached the servo rotates until the limit.

Comment: Have you tried the default examples? If you go to File -> examples ->servo, there are 2 scripts, sweep and knob. Try them. Also, use external power source for servo, do not power it from Arduino 5V

Comment: I've tried the Sweep one, as it is simpler, and keep the servo unplugged from power until the program is uploaded. Then I connect the battery and the servo runs out the limit :(

Comment: Well...I think is a cable problem...it seems that the long cable I connected between the servo and the arduino board is too long (1.5m) and mess with the signal, does it make any sense?